# I'm never going to guess the answer if you don't give me a clue. / I will never guess the answer if you don't give me a clue

Tags: conditional-constructions, will-vs-going-to

From Oxford dictionary I have the first sentence. But from my grammar book is the following quote: "When the future event doesn't depend on the action described in the *if-clause*, we use *be going to, not will*." So, is it not better to use "will" in this example because there is a need for a clue?

> **I'm never going to guess the answer** if you don't give me a clue.
>
> **I will never guess the answer** if you don't give me a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, *be going to* is the standard future tense of English. Almost everywhere you can use "will", or *present continuous* or *simple present* with future meaning, you could use *be going to* instead. Another way of thinking about this is, "To choose a future verb other than *be going to*, you need a good reason."

There are several future contexts where "will" is correct, but that doesn't mean *only* "will" is correct. Often, *be going to* is also correct.

This is one of the situations where *be going to* is also correct.

It's probably more common for people to use "will" in a context like this, but only because it's shorter. Both sound 100% natural.

Comment: Perhaps, in practice, there is no difference in meaning, as you say that but my grammar book (Cambridge University Press) says that "I'm going to open a bottle of limonade, if you want some." & "I'll open a bottle of limonade if you want some." have different meaning.  "I'm going to open a bottle of limonade, if you want some." mean that I will open that bottle of limonade anyway.

Comment: Your example about lemonade is one of the contexts I mentioned in my answer where you have a good reason to choose "will": you're making an offer. "Will" is used for making offers, but "be going to" usually isn't. Also, without the comma (only one of your examples has a comma), the "be going to" version could also mean "I'm only going to open the bottle if you want some."